# Removing text that was appended previously

Tags: jquery, css, prepend

I have a highlighting function using JQuery, that changes the css for the clicked `<li>` element in a menu.  The function also prepends a pair of left brackets << to serve as pseudo arrows.

But how do I remove that << when I switch to the next `<li>` ?

```
$(".sdv-nrml").click(function(){

//remove old highlighted li 
$(".sdv-nrml").css({'background' : '#ffcc66' , 'color' : '#000000' , 'text-align' : 'right'});

//assign new css and prepend arrow
$(this).css({'background' : '#996600' , 'color' : '#ffff66' , 'text-align' : 'left'});
$(this).prepend("<< ");
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would include the `<<` in a `<span>`:

```
$(this).prepend('<span class="prepended">&laquo; </span');
```

then to remove:

```
$(".prepended").remove();
```

Note: I used « instead of <<. I find it a little more appealing.

Comment: note: minor error.  class was named "prependED" referred to as .prepend  great solution though, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 7):

Wrap it in a `span` with a `class` and remove that.

```
$(this).prepend('<span class="pseudo-arrow">&lt;&lt;</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don user a class for the selected state?
    .selected-item {
        background: #ffcc66;
        color: #000;
        text-align:right;
    }

So your script can be used like that:

```
$(".sdv-nrml").click(function(){

    //remove old highlighted li
    $(".sdv-nrml").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("selected arrow");
    });

    //assign new css and prepend arrow
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).prepend("<span class='arrow'>&lt;&lt;</span> ");
});
```